# Using Vaadin visual editor disables custom syntax highlighting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, vaadin, vaadin7

I have found that after using the Vaadin visual editor in eclipse Kepler (haven't tried others).. if I make any changes with the visual editor -  it disables almost all the syntax highlighting I use.

To be more exact, all custom coloring except for keywords, comments and strings is reverted to a default color - since by default only these 3 elements have different colors, there is an obvious connection.. I use a high contrast theme and I find it useful to use a lot of colors in my code, it helps me get more information out of it with less reading/searching.

The editor does not change the settings of the syntax highlighting - only that one tab that is opened with the visual editor changes, after I made changes using Vaadin visual editor.

A workaround is to simply close the tab and reopen it in a Java editor, then reopening it in the visual editor will revert back to the highlighting I've set, but if I do any changes in the visual editor I have to do this again.

Does anyone know what causes this or better -  how to 'fix' it - ie so the visual editor doesnt change my syntax highlighting - it's not cataclysmic, but it is really annoying.